# How to iterate through list in a function properly

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

```
users = [{"username":"tom", "password":1234},{"username":"pete", "password":1234},{"username":"lisa", "password":1234}]

loged_in = False

def login(log):
    while loged_in == False:
        username_check = input("Please enter your username")
        password_check = str(input("Please enter your password"))
        for user in users:
            if username_check == user["username"] and str(password_check) == str(user["password"]):
                print("Welcome, you're logged in.")
                loged_in == True
                break
            if username_check != user["username"] or str(password_check) != str(user["password"]):
                print("Wrong username or password, please try again.")
                continue
```

How do I make it show if the log in was succesful/unsuccesful only once, instead of showing the result for every item on the list? Like this:

"Wrong username or password, please try again."

"Wrong username or password, please try again."

"Wrong username or password, please try again."

Comment: It's a typo; `loged_in == True` is a comparison that just gets thrown away. You at least need `loged_in = True` to be an assignment (single `=`; I can't guarantee it fixes other issues)

Comment: why do you loop over all users while you ask only once for the login/pass?

Comment: Also, it's "logged" not "loged" but that's a separate thing

Comment: and think about your data structure - instead of list of dicts, just dict where key is the username  and password is the value is much better It will allow for much simpler code

Comment: When iterating through a list like this, you only know if the wrong username or password was entered if you get right to the end with no matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the user/pass checking logic into it's own method. This will make it much easier to determine how to structure the loop.

Here's an example of a method that will return a user if the username and password is valid, and otherwise it will return nothing if the inputs are incorrect.

```
def validate_user_pass(users, username, password):
    for user in users:
        if (username, password) == (user["username"], user["password"]):
            return user
    return None
```

Now your login method can look like this:

```
while True:
    username = input("Please enter your username")
    password = input("Please enter your password")
    user = validate_user_pass(users, username, password)
    if user:
        print("Welcome, you're logged in.")
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong username or password, please try again.")
```

Comment: thanks it works but can you tell me what's the purpose of the "users" argumnet in the first function

Comment: and can you explain what "if user:" means? if user what?

Comment: @Domi If possible, I like to avoid having functions rely on outside state. Although other parts of the code use the `users` from the global state, this can make the code inflexible to change. Imagine in a couple months you changed this design to handle two different systems, and those systems had different sets of users. When we use the `users` variable from the global scope, we leave ourselves with no way to swap it out for the users in the second system. Instead if we provide the data into the method, we can easily swap out the set of users by passing in a different list as an argument.

Comment: @Domi `if user:` is testing if the value is `None` or not. In this case its basically the same as writing `if user is not None:` , and we want to test for that, because we return `None` if we couldn't find a user.

Answer (score 2):

You code had several implementation errors. Here is a simpler functional version:

```
users = {"tom": 1234, "pete": 1234, "lisa": 1234}
# NB. to convert the previous list format into a dictionary, use:
# users = {d['username']: d['password'] for d in users}

def login(log):         # not sure what log is for here
    logged_in = False   # initialize in the function (or it will be True forever once a successful login is made
    while not logged_in:  # no need to compare booleans to booleans
        username_check = input("Please enter your username")
        password_check = input("Please enter your password") # no need for str conversion, input is already str
        if username_check in users and password_check == str(users[username_check]):
            print("Welcome, you're logged in.")
            logged_in = True # this and the line below are redundant
            break
        else: # no need to test the previous condition again
            print("Wrong username or password, please try again.")
```

Comment: Hmm, `logged_in` seems redundant.

Comment: I see what you mean, yes the variable is useless in this context, I left it as it might be used for something else. Same thing with the `log`, not clue what this is for, I left it there

Answer (score 2):

Make a variable (e.g state=0). In the for loop if the login was successful then give it 1 (state=1) if there was an error give it a number for the error.
Based on your state, after for loop print a result of login.
something like:

```
users = [{"username":"tom", "password":1234},{"username":"pete", "password":1234},{"username":"lisa", "password":1234}]

logged_in = False

def login(log):
    while logged_in == False:
        state = 0
        username_check = input("Please enter your username")
        password_check = str(input("Please enter your password"))
        for user in users:
            if username_check == user["username"] and str(password_check) == str(user["password"]):
                state = 1
                logged_in = True
                break
        if state == 1:
            print("Welcome, you're logged in.")
        else:
            print("Wrong username or password, please try again.")
```

or just:

```
users = [{"username":"tom", "password":1234},{"username":"pete", "password":1234},{"username":"lisa", "password":1234}]

logged_in = False

def login(log):
    while logged_in == False:
        username_check = input("Please enter your username")
        password_check = str(input("Please enter your password"))
        for user in users:
            if username_check == user["username"] and str(password_check) == str(user["password"]):
                logged_in = True
                break
        if logged_in  == False:
            print("Wrong username or password, please try again.")
    else:
        print("Welcome, you're logged in.")
```

Comment: The second `if` inside the `for` is entirely redundant and can be removed.

Comment: Very true. Thanks.

Comment: But it gives an error : in login
    while logged_in == False:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'logged_in' referenced before assignment

Comment: I just considered the printing part error, not the login mechanism.